# Using imaplib to get headers of emails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, imaplib

Here is my code:

```
    conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    conn.login('username', 'password')
    conn.select()
    typ, data = conn.search(None, "ALL")
    parser1 = HeaderParser()
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        header_data = str(data[1][0])
        msg = email.message_from_string(header_data)
        print(msg.keys())
        print(msg['Date'])
```

Why am i getting "[]" for the printout of msg.keys() and "None" for the msg['Date']. No error messages. However, if i comment out the last 4 lines of code, and type print(data), then all the headers get printed? Im using python 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conn.fetch` returns [tuples of message part envelope and data](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.fetch). For some reason -- I'm not sure why -- it may also return a string, such as `')'`. So instead of hard-coding `data[1][0]`, it's better (more robust) to just loop through the tuples in `data` and parse the message parts:

```
typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
for response_part in msg_data:
    if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
        msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
```

---

For example,

```
import imaplib
import config
import email

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
conn.login(config.GMAIL_USER2, config.GMAIL_PASS2)
try:
    conn.select()

    typ, data = conn.search(None, "ALL")
    print(data)
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                part = response_part[1].decode('utf-8')
                msg = email.message_from_string(part)
                print(msg.keys())
                print(msg['Date'])
finally:
    try:
        conn.close()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        conn.logout()
```

Much of this code comes from [Doug Hellman's imaplib tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/#whole-messages).

Comment: I have just tried this and i didnt get an error message. But nothing at all prints. I will go over it again just to be sure

Comment: If you are running the code I posted and *nothing* prints, then `data` is an empty string since there is a `print(data)` in there.

Comment: TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes is the error message i get

Comment: My mistake. With Python3 you must decode the bytes in `response_part[1]` before parsing it with `email.message_from_string`.